# Instantiate a class with decorator ( mobx ) - React : Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Looking for insights with this one.

Say we have

```
class Thing {

  doSomething() { ... }
}
```

and we can

```
const testThing = new Thing()
testThing.doSomething()
```

How, in React, say when we inject with MobX and it wraps everthing can we instantiate ?

```
@inject('storeThing')
class Thing {

  doSomething() { ... }
}
```

now ...

```
const testThing = new Thing()
testThing.doSomething() /* doSomething undefined because we have the decorator instead */
```

Without using enzyme etc *( I know how with shallow/mount(Component.wrapper... )*  .. in pure JS; how would we call this class to do some basic unit testing ?

Thanks. Hope I made sense.

Comment: Does `testThing.wrappedInstance.doSomething()` help?

Comment: Thanks @Danila . Normally this would, right for `connect` ? `wrappedInstance` is  `undefined` in the case of the MOBX decorator `@inject( ` diff thing

Comment: I am thinking that the Class does not get Instantiated at all @Danila. Part of the internal workings on the React/MobX setup .. only Instantiate when needed but it is 'Ready' ?